# Subrequests are not sent or the request hangs

Tags: c, nginx

I'm trying to write my own module in C (it has to be C) for Nginx 1.7.12.
It is meant to send additional request to another server, when proxied request arrives to Nginx.

For this I've created two locations in config:

```
        location = / {
                 proxy_pass                 $backend_url;
        }
        location /internal_url {
                 proxy_pass                 $log_server_url;
                 internal;
        }
```

I've used examples from [here](http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide-advanced.html#subrequests) to create a filter presented below:

```
static ngx_int_t my_http_body_filter(ngx_http_request_t* r,    
                                     ngx_chain_t* in)
{
  int                 rc;
  ngx_str_t           uri = SOME_INTERNAL_URI;
  ngx_http_request_t *sr;

  rc = ngx_http_next_body_filter(r, in);

  if (rc == NGX_ERROR)
    return rc;

  return ngx_http_subrequest(r, &uri, NULL /* args */, &sr,
                           NULL /* callback */, 0 /* flags */);
}
```

At first, it seemed as if subrequests are never sent. I had experimented with `NGX_AGAIN`, and `subrequest->done` but I was able only to make the request hang.

Then, it turned out that subrequests are, in fact, sent (so the configuration is OK) when I add `return NGX_AGAIN;`, after `ngx_http_subrequest` call.

Unfortunately, then the original request never finishes.

How this should be done?

Comment: Does your uri match any location within nginx.conf? It should be '/internal_url' if I understood your config right.

Comment: @Alexander Altshuler: it matches, (it's something like "/internal_url/subpage")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this will work?

```
static ngx_int_t my_http_body_filter(ngx_http_request_t* r,
                                     ngx_chain_t* in)
{
  int                 rc;
  ngx_str_t           uri = SOME_INTERNAL_URI;
  ngx_http_request_t *sr;

  if (r != r->main) { /* subrequest */
    return ngx_http_next_body_filter(r, in);
  }

  return ngx_http_subrequest(r, &uri, NULL /* args */, &sr,
                           NULL /* callback */, 0 /* flags */);
}
```

**Update:**

After some investigation this is a new version:
[gist](https://gist.github.com/altexy/2e5a3f7737d3d5c58b00)

Unfortunately I don't have a chance to test my code at the moment.

**Update**

Code above sends subrequest upon receiving full body.
Another possible approach is to send it on first chunk and store flag in context.

Comment: it generates loop with many (probably 255) subrequest calls  and no response is returned to client. But I'll experiment a little with it.

Comment: I've added context with flag so `ngx_http_subrequest` is called only once, and in result I'm receiving `curl: (18) transfer closed with XXX bytes remaining to read`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/altexy/2e5a3f7737d3d5c58b00 works, thanks! (I'll probably try modify it to set flag, but at least I have a place to start)